# How to remove rows from multiindex dataframe with string indices

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiindex, from which I want to delete rows according to some index based pattern. For example, I would like to remove frames 1-4 where the annotator is "Peter Test xx" and the label is "empty' in the dataframe below

```
print df
                                        boundingbox x1  boundingbox y1  \
frame  annotator              label                                          
0      Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN   
1      Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN   
2      Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN   
3      Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN   
       Petaa                  yea                      NaN             NaN   
4      Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN   
5      P                      empty frame              494              64   
       Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN   
6      P                      empty frame              494              64   
       Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN   
7      P                      empty frame              494              64   
       Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN   
8      P                      empty frame              494              64   
       Peter Test xx          empty                    NaN             NaN
```

I can select rows by  doing something like

```
indexer = [slice(None)]*len(df.index.names)
indexer[df.index.names.index('frame')] = range(1,4)
indexer[df.index.names.index('annotator')] = ['Peter Test xx']
indexer[df.index.names.index('label')] = ['empty']
return df.loc[tuple(indexer),:]
```

If I want to delete these rows, ideally I would like to do something like

```
del df.loc[tuple(indexer),:]
```

But this does not work (why?). All solutions I found online were based on int based indices. But if I am working with strings as indices, I cannot simply slice or such things.

Something I tried as well was:

```
def filterFunc(x, frames, annotator, label):
    if x[0] in frames\
    and x[1] == annotator\
    and x[2] == label:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

mask = df.index.map(lambda x: filterFunc(x, frames, annotator, label))

return df[~mask,:]
```

Which gives me:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve another problem I figured out that one can use the index of a selected part of a dataframe in `drop`:

```
indexer = [slice(None)]*len(df.index.names)
indexer[df.index.names.index('frame')] = range(1,4)
indexer[df.index.names.index('annotator')] = ['Peter Test xx']
indexer[df.index.names.index('label')] = ['empty']
selection = df.loc[tuple(indexer),:]
df.drop(selection.index)
```

Is that how it is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use loc, iloc or ix when doing more complicated slicing:

```
df[msk]  # works

df.iloc[msk, ]  # works
df.iloc[msk, :]  # works
```

but

```
df[msk, ]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

*See [different choices for indexing in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing).*

Comment: ohhk. I would have to use `iloc`... what is the difference to `loc`? However, if I index with `df.iloc[mask,:]` then I get a completely mixed up "frame" index (swapping between 0 and 1) + the data seems to be strange as well.

Comment: @P.R. hmmm unclear what your seeing, in my examples it works fine. What version of pandas are you using? Check out the docs I link to for the difference between loc and iloc.